# Python LRU cache in a class disregards maxsize limit when decorated with a staticmethod or classmethod decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, lru

I was going through the implementation [details](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py#L430) of Python's LRU cache decorator and noticed this behavior that I found a bit surprising. When decorated with either `staticmethod` or `classmethod` decorator, `lru_cache` disregards the `maxsize` limit. Consider this example:

```py
# src.py

import time
from functools import lru_cache


class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    @lru_cache(3)
    def bar(x):
        time.sleep(3)
        return x + 5


def main():
    foo = Foo()
    print(foo.bar(10))
    print(foo.bar(10))
    print(foo.bar(10))

    foo1 = Foo()
    print(foo1.bar(10))
    print(foo1.bar(10))
    print(foo1.bar(10))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

From the implementation, it's clear to me that using the LRU cache decorator in this way will create a shared cache for all the instances of class `Foo`. However, when I run the code, it waits for 3 seconds in the beginning and then prints out `15` six times without pausing in the middle.

```
$ python src.py 
# Waits for three seconds and then prints out 15 six times
15
15
15
15
15
15
```

I was expecting it to—

- Wait for 3 seconds.
- Then print `15` three times.
- Then wait again for 3 seconds.
- And finally, print `15` three times.

Running the above code with an instance method behaves in the way that I've explained in the bullet points.

Inspecting the `foo.bar` method with cache info gives me the following result:

```py
print(f"{foo.bar.cache_info()=}")
print(f"{foo1.bar.cache_info()=}")
```

```
foo.bar.cache_info()=CacheInfo(hits=5, misses=1, maxsize=3, currsize=1)
foo1.bar.cache_info()=CacheInfo(hits=5, misses=1, maxsize=3, currsize=1)
```

How is this possible? The cache info named tuple is the same for both `foo` and `foo1` instance—which is expected—but how come the LRU cache is behaving as if it was applied as `lru_cache(None)(func)`. Is this because of descriptor intervention or something else? Why is it disregarding the cache limit? Why does running the code with an instance method works as explained above?

***Edit:*** *As Klaus mentioned in the comment that this is caching 3 keys, not 3 accesses. So, for a key to be evicted, the method needs to be called at least 4 times with different arguments. That explains why it's quickly printing `15` six times without pausing in the middle. It's not exactly disregarding the maxlimit.*

*Also, in the case of an instance method, `lru_cache` utilizes the `self` argument to hash and build the key for each argument in the cache dictionary. So each new instance method will have a different key for the same argument due to the inclusion of `self` in the hash calculation. For static methods, there's no `self` argument and for class methods, the `cls` is the same class in different instances. This explains the differences in their behaviors.*

Comment: Like this you are caching 3 keys, not 3 accesses. For a key to be dropped you need at least 4 *different* calls.

Comment: Hmm..in that case, why does it act differently on an instance method? In the case of an instance method, running the code above waits for 3 seconds, then prints 15 thrice, then waits again for 3 seconds, and finally prints 15 thrice. I still find this a tad bit weird.

Comment: The instance is part of the call. New instance, new cache key.

Comment: I see. So basically it uses the `self` argument in the cache's hashed key, right? Do you mind adding that as an answer that I can accept? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said in your edit, the `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod` decorators will make the cache be shared among all instances.

```py
import time
from functools import lru_cache


class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    @lru_cache(3)
    def foo(x):
        time.sleep(1)
        return x + 5


class Bar:
    @lru_cache(3)
    def bar(self, x):
        time.sleep(1)
        return x + 5

def main():
    # fill the shared cache takes around 3 seconds
    foo0 = Foo()
    print(foo0.foo(10), foo0.foo(11), foo0.foo(12))

    # get from the shared cache takes very little time
    foo1 = Foo()
    print(foo1.foo(10), foo1.foo(11), foo1.foo(12))

    # fill the instance 0 cache takes around 3 seconds
    bar0 = Bar()
    print(bar0.bar(10), bar0.bar(11), bar0.bar(12))

    # fill the instance 1 cache takes around 3 seconds again 
    bar1 = Bar()
    print(bar1.bar(10), bar1.bar(11), bar1.bar(12))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```